# Angular 4 imports in .less file is not updating on change

Tags: css, angular, typescript, import, less

I'm currently building a small Angular project where I'm using less for styling.

I wanted to break out the styling into separate folders away from the components and have a major import file instead: main.less, which only consists of imports from the stylesheets around it.
For example:

```
buttons/buttons.less

header/header.less

hero/hero.less
```

These are imported in main.less.
This means that my components doesn't use the styleURL property, instead it relies on a global stylesheet.

In my angular.json I've pointed the styles to it, like this:

```
"styles": [ 
    "src/app/less/main.less" 
]
```

When I run ng serve it works just fine but when I change something in buttons.less it refreshes the page (as expected) but the change is not applied. This goes for every import file in main.less.
But if I add the button.less file directly in "styles" in angular.json it works like a charm.
Also, if I add style directly in the main.less file and for example adding this, that line works:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, why won't it handle my imports? If I restart the angular server it recompiles the files and tada.wav, the changes are added.
No errors are logged through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to less-loader 4.x.x, which has been reported on Angulars github page.

Downgrading to less-loader 3.x.x solves the problem.
Simply use:

npm install --save-dev less-loader@3.0.0

Tada.wav

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the server to watch for changes.

```
ng serve --watch
```

Comment: uhm no, it does that out of the box. either way, it didn't work with ng serve --watch.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was an issue in one of the `less` versions. The question has been discussed here:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader/issues/252

There are two options:

- Update to less@2.7.3
- Update to less@3.7.1

I have tried both these versions and they work with `less-loader": "4.1.0"`. Previously i had `less@3.0.4` and the update of imported .less modules did not trigger page hot reload.